# Is it possible to create a 'site-to-site' VPN using an iOS device?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, apple-ios, wireguard

I am trying to configure a VPN that would allow remote access to the LAN of an iOS client from the VPN server, as a remote-access solution not requiring any dedicated hardware or setup on the client's network.

Using OpenVPN or WireGuard, I can configure routing such that the IP range of the target LAN would be routed to the server's VPN interface, and then the client - that's the easy part.

To get a proof-of-concept working, first on macOS using OpenVPN, I had to resort to enabling IP forwarding and NAT on the client to allow the traffic to flow from the client's VPN interface to LAN interface.

You obviously can't go in and enable forwarding and NAT on iOS, so I just wanted to confirm that there's no OpenVPN `route` or WireGuard `Allowed IPs` value(or any other config option) I could set to allow a similar sort of site-to-site behaviour using an iOS client.

I've tried to scan through the docs but my routing and VPN setup skills are somewhat rusty so some expert input would be appreciated! TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is no (known or supported) routing capability on IOS. You can just "dial in" and use that tunnel interface locally. No NAT, no other routing protcols.

Technically it *should* be possible to use the tether (aka WiFi AP) function of your IOS device to connect a  VPN gateway or justmore clients to the internet and your VPN, but that'd be very hacky (and probably unstable).

Comment: Sounds like the tether functionality would count as client setup needed too unfortunately